Electromotive force by PN junction and extraneous role of electrolyte in electrochemical cells
When the two semiconductors N and P are connected, because of higher Fermi energy, electrons migrate from N to P so that an electric filed is formed in the depletion region (attached picture) which balances the Fermi energy. Now, it seems that if we attach a wire to the PN junction the electrons in the wire are pushed from P side to N side (because of the force by negative charges of the P region and positive charge of the N region). By reaching to the N side the electrons neutralize the positive charges in that region and simultaneously in a similar manner the electrons in the P side decreases. So, again the Fermi energy of the two regions becomes unbalanced and consequently the electrons migrate from N to P region which keep the depletion region unaltered and the process repeats. Therefore, if this description is correct, we can use the simple PN junction as a battery. So, my question is: what is the role of electrolyte in the more complicated electrochemical cell? I would be grateful if anyone please correct me if I am wrong.  

The electrochemical reaction is a migration of positive ions through the battery from the negative to the positive side. Electrons flowing through the wire keeps the system neutral, allowing the reaction to continue. If the circuit is opened, the electron field inside the battery interrupts the ions migration.
In the PN junction there is no ions migration. The electrons from the conduction band of the N side go to the valence band of the P side until an equilibrium is reached between electric field and chemical potential.
A continuous current as you describe would mean: electrons in the valence band of P side flow through the wire and climb to the conduction band of the N side in order to keep the process running. But the energy to that climbing must come from somewhere. For example: from a electrochemical battery.

Thank you very much for your answer. It seems that since Fermi energy is identical throughout the system electrons don't need energy for going from P to N side and vice versa. I think I found the answer. In contrast with my supposition, out of depletion region, the electric field is zero and there is no force to drive the electrons in the wire. In fact, negative charges of the P region don't induce electric field outside the depletion region to push electrons in the wire towards P side.

@H. Khani Your reasoning with the missing electric field outside the charges of the depletion region is not correct. In an isolated  charged capacitor, you also have no electric field in the metal region next to the plate charges, but you get a nice current, when you connect the plates by a wire due to the plate's potential difference.

It is a well-known fact that out of depletion region electric field is zero otherwise the band structure must have a sloped form. Also, the comparison with capacitor is not relevant here because there is a potential difference between the capacitor's plates and this potential difference is not made by a chemical potential.

As far as I know the electric field inside the metallic wire is zero only in the electrostatic case but when you attach the wire to the battery an electric field inside the wire drive the charges.

@H. Khani The potential difference in a capacitor also corresponds to a difference in chemical potential of the metal plates. Your reasoning doesn't make sense!

Right, but when a capacitor is discharged there is no chemical potential between the plates so the charge transfer must stop while if the depletion region became discharged the different chemical potential of the two semiconductors would compensate and recharge.

@H. Khani As long as a system is in thermodynamic equilibrium, i.e., it has a constant (electro-)chemical potential throughout, there will be no current.  The pn-junction, because(!) of the depletion charges is in thermodynamic equilibrium, thus it produces no current in spite of the potential difference when you connect its ends with a wire  which is in thermodynamic equilibrium with the pn-junction and thus produces compensating contact potential differences  that prevent any current flow.

You cannot use a pn-junction as a battery. Even though the n-side is at a higher electrical potential than the p-side due to the contact potential difference (called built-in voltage) of the n- and p-semiconductor junction. When you apply metal contacts, the metal also has a contact potential differences to the two semiconductor sides which exactly compensate the voltage difference, so that there is no net potential difference in the circuit loop, which would produce a current and thus energy in spite of being in thermal equilibrium. This is also the reason why with a usual voltmeter you cannot measure the potential difference of the pn-junction. In electrochemical batteries the voltage difference of the terminals is produced by internal chemical redox-reactions.

Thanks, but your reasoning of zero potential over the loop is not convincing because in a circuit including even a battery also this event occurs.

@H. Kani A circuit with a battery is not in "thermal equilibrium" unless the battery is discharged and "dead". Thermal equilibrium  means that the Fermi level (chemical potential) is constant throughout the system. A current arises when there is a difference of Fermi level.
